# Get ArrayList index

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to access the current index of an array list but can't figure out how to do it in the following method:

```
public String getNextMessage(){
    String s = getMessageArray(index);
    index++;
    return s;
}
```

The "getMessageArray" comes up with an error and I don't know hwo to resolve it. This method worked with Arrays[] but I don't know how to do it with an ArrayList. Here is the whole class file:

```
package com.game.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Message {

private int index;
private ArrayList<String> messageArray;

private String intro = "Welcome.";

public Message() {
    messageArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    messageArray.add(intro);
}

public String getNextMessage(){
    String s = getMessageArray(index);
    index++;
    return s;
}

public ArrayList<String> getMessageArray() {
    return messageArray;
}

public void setMessageArray(ArrayList<String> messageArray) {
    this.messageArray = messageArray;
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your `getMessageArray(int something)` function? I don't see it here

Comment: Lists (including `ArrayList`) do not have a "current index". Only `ListIterator` instances you obtain from them have one (sort of).

Comment: There is no such thing as "current index" intrinsic to ArrayList. You need to export `index` getter from `Message` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in an earlier answer

```
public String getNextMessage(){
    String s = messages.get(indx);
    indx++;
    return s;
}
```

however, it seems you changed the part where the list is accessed from

```
String s = messages.get(indx);
```

to

```
String s = getMessageArray(index);
```

The reason your version doesnt work is, that the you are trying to call a method called getMessageArray(index), that returns the ArrayList object itself, which is an ArrayList. What you actually want to do is to call the get()-method of the ArrayList class.

You have declared a variable called **messages** earlier in your class

```
private ArrayList<String> messages;
```

Here you can see **messages** is of type **ArrayList**. ArrayList has a method called **get(int index)** which retrieves the element at the specified index.

You can call this method the way I wrote at the beginning of this answer.

For reference, you can view all methods available on arraylist [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 1):

I guess your first line in `getNextMessage()` should be:

```
String s = getMessageArray().get(index);
```

There is no such method as: `getMessageArray(int)` in your class. It's the method with 0-arg, which returns an `ArrayList`, on which you use the `List#get(int)` method to access the value at some index.

In fact, you can simply access the `messageArray` directly in that method, as it's in the same class only. So, that line can be better written as:

```
String s = messageArray.get(index);
```

Now, given that you are not doing anything between fetching the value at that index, and returning that value, apart from incrementing the index, you can shorten your method to a one-liner:

```
public String getNextMessage(){
    return messageArray.get(index++);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
getMessageArray(index);
```

write

```
getMessageArray.get(index);
```

you must first get the array list then specify the index you want to get.